# Need to exit the react-native app when clicking on back button but only from Homepage

Tags: react-native

I need to exit the react-native app only when I am on Homepage(Screen) and click on back button, I have written the code but it exits the app from every screen. I am using Router-Flux for routing, Kindly someone help me to fix my issue,So far I have tried:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackPress);
}
componentWillUnmount() {       
BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", 
this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {

Alert.alert(
'Exit App',
'Do you want to exit?',
[
{text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 
'cancel'},
{text: 'Yes', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
],
{ cancelable: false });
return true;
};

Code in my component Homepage.js

import { BackHandler, Alert} from 'react-native';
componentDidMount = async () => {
BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUnmount() {      
BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", 
this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {

Alert.alert(
'Exit App',
'Do you want to exit?',

 [
{text: 'No', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 
'cancel'},
{text: 'Yes', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
],
{ cancelable: false });
return true;
};

Code in my Routes.js

import { Router, Stack, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
<Router>
<Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
<Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" initial={true} />
<Scene key="homepage" component={Homepage} title="Home"  />
<Scene key="history" component={HistoryAll} title="HistoryAll" />
</Stack>
</Router>

I was expecting that when I am on Homepage.Js and click on back button it 
will exit the app, its happening but it exits the App from every screen 
of the app.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Actions.state.index` as a check . If it is equal to 1 then exit app otherwise you can `pop()` or use any other functionality as per your requirement.

```
onBackPress() {

        if (Actions.state.index === 1) {

            BackHandler.exitApp();
            return false;
        }

        Actions.pop();
        return true;

    }
```

Hope it helps !